# How can I download Snow Leopard?

Tags: upgrade, leopard

I am running a MacBook Pro on Mac OS X 10.5.8

I want to upgrade to Mountain Lion, but cannot download it as I do not have Snow Leopard.

I cannot find Snow Leopard to download. Where might I get this?

Comment: Which country do you live in?

Comment: ~~I live in England

Comment: Are you buying Mountain Lion from Apple Store?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it. I use ipad for work and want to get icloud on my mac so i can sync everything and use the same apps such as numbers and pages. Reccommendations?

Comment: Ok, ignore me if I'm stating something you already know. You can sync among your iOS devices just by setting their iCloud with the same account AND without needing iCloud on the Mac OS X. However, if you want to sync iWork documents among iOS devices and OS X Macs, then you'll need iCloud on OS X (hence purchasing OS X makes sense). Note however, that iWork on iOS isn't equivalent on iWork on OS X -- missing some features.

Comment: Can your Macbook Pro even run Mountain Lion? I would be very surprised to learn that anything that ran Leopard could also run Mountain Lion. Apple posts a list of models as the [system requirements](http://www.apple.com/osx/specs/).

Comment: Jason Salaz, as you can see from the link you posted, Mountain Lion runs on the MacBook Pro Mid/Late 2007 or newer; that model originally shipped with Tiger.

Answer (score 3):

Snow Leopard was only officially available on DVD, so you would need to buy a copy of that before you can buy the Mountain Lion upgrade if you want to stick to the official upgrade path.

[Apple still sells Snow Leopard media as well](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard?fnode=568bc6ab5e72af0fc4dfe2880fa5ba01b8feca4023686acb862c670b4d516680646b68b76d8eda36f8469c9ab6d96815f0ce339c4eabadff2abf582ddda6902565f53285fc932ddefc4c2708c7bb50d1eb754cabce4f6f3a3fa5c401d8aea47b)

Comment: Ok thanks. What are the other ways?

Comment: Illegally downloading it (breach of copyright law) or borrowing someone else's copy (breach of licensing agreement).

Answer (score 2):

Apple still sells Snow Leopard via Phone Sales.  Call the number at the top left of the screen at store.apple.com/uk and you can purchase a DVD copy of Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Snow Leopard was available only on DVD. You can buy old ones on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-Leopard-Operating-System-version/dp/B007KOLP3U/ref=sr_1_31?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1344790380&sr=1-31). If you don’t want to buy it, you can borrow a DVD from a friend. Or you can go to an Apple Store. If you find someone friendly there, they will upgrade you for free.

If you were a MobileMe, you could get Snow Leopard for free. I don’t know if Apple still has that up in the UK.

Comment: eBay works as well